# RavenDB - querying issue - Stale results/indexes

Tags: nosql, ravendb

While querying RavenDB I am noticing that it does not get the expected results immediately. May be it has to do with indexing, I dont know.

For example :

```
   int ACount = session.Query<Patron>()
                   .Count();

   int BCount = session.Query<Theaters>()
                   .Count();

   int CCount = session.Query<Movies>()
                   .Where(x => x.Status == "Released")                                              
                   .Count();

   int DCount = session.Query<Promotions>()
                    .Count();
```

When I execute this then `ACount` and `BCount` get their values immediately on the first run). However `CCount` and `DCount` do not get their values until after three or four runs. They show 0 (zero) value in the first few runs.

Why does this happen for bottom two and not top two queries? If its because of stale results (or indexes) then how can I modify my queries to get the accurate results every time, when I run it first time. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you haven't defined an index for the Movies query, Raven will create a [Dynamic Index](http://ayende.com/blog/4667/ravens-dynamic-queries). If you use the query repeatedly the index will be automatically persisted. Otherwise Raven will discard it and that may explain why you're getting 0 results during the first few runs.

You can also instruct Raven to wait for the indexing process to ensure that you'll always get the most accurate results (even though this might not be a good idea as it will slow your queries) by using the **WaitForNonStaleResults** instruction:

```
session.Query<Movies>()
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
.Where(x => x.Status == "Released")                                              
.Count();
```

Comment: How do I address the timeout issue? I am getting a time out error when I am using the .waitfornonstaleresults() in the query.

Comment: TimeOutException unhandled by user code: {"Waited for 15,250ms for the query to return non stale result."} - is the message. .

Comment: I used... .  Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100))) to fix the time out exception.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer this might not be a good idea as it will slow your queries. You don't really want to have "someone" waiting a few seconds for the results. Could you further explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to query the database and display a few numbers in a web page based on the Count values of queries that I run. If this is not a good idea, how can I run these four queries so that I get the numbers (count) calculated accurately and in timely fashion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The underlying principle in Raven is that writes don't delay reads. That's why I'm saying that using the WaitForNonStaleResults option may not be the best option. You're using a dynamic index for your counts that if used frequently, will be promoted from a temporary to a permanent index. And in that case it will always have the data pre-calculated. So you'll get your results even without using WaitForNonStaleResults. I strongly recommend the following webinar by Ayende, as he discusses some of these concepts - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEnKjeB1b38

Comment: Frequently? how frequently, is there a number? and thanks for the webinar link.

Comment: You can choose how frequently by changing the Raven/TempIndexPromotionMinimumQueryCount configuration which defines "how many times a temporary, auto-generated index has to be accessed before it can be promoted to be a permanent one". The default is 100. Please take a look at [Raven's Configuration Options page](http://ravendb.net/documentation/configuration)

Comment: @Carlos: This "WaitFor.." construction  instruct Raven to wait for entire indexing process to finish, or just this one connected with "Movies" only ?

Answer (score 1):

Needing to put WaitForNonStaleResults in each query feels like a massive "code smell" (as much as I normally hate the term, it seems completely appropriate here).

The only real solution I've found so far is:

```
var store = new DocumentStore(); // do whatever
store.DatabaseCommands.DisableAllCaching();
```

Performance suffers accordingly, but I think slower performance is far less of a sin than unreliable if not outright inaccurate results.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options according to [the official documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/all/indexes/stale-indexes) (the most preferable first):

1. **Setting cut-off point**.

   `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` 
   or 
   `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()`

   This will make sure that you get the latest results up to that point in time (or till the last write). And you can put a cap on it (e.g. 10s), if you want to sacrifice freshness of the results to receiving the response faster.
2. **Explicitly waiting for non-stale results**
   `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))`

   Again, specifying a time-out would be a good practice.
3. **Setting querying conventions** to apply the same rule to all requests

   `store.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.AlwaysWaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite`.